# linking one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, anchor

This is a very simple question, but as I am a newbie...

I have two files: login.jsp and report.jsp
they are both within the same WebContent folder.

I want a link on report.jsp that when clicked, will take me to login.jsp

The jsp part of the page looks like:

```
Connection conn = (Connection)session.getAttribute("conn"); //retrieves the connection from the session

String lot_id = request.getParameter("lotnum");
session.setAttribute("lot_id",lot_id);

out.print("Report on Lot Number: ");
out.print(request.getParameter("lotnum")+"<br>");


//<a href="login.jsp">Click here to go to login page</a>
// this is supposed to be an anchor tag linking this page to login.jsp, and where I am getting my error... 

Statement sql = conn.createStatement();  //create statement using the connection

//... ... code for the rest of the page goes here...
```

thank you,

much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try put your folder name:

```
out.print("<a href='/foldername/login.jsp'>Click here to go to login page</a>");
```

Comment: how silly of me. of course... out.print can send html code... thank you!